# Getting EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION for random color generator

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to create a random color generator where I'm supposed to select the right color. My code is as follows:

```
var colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Dark"];

var targetColor = "";

@IBAction func touchTheColor(_ sender: Any) {

    if colors[(sender as AnyObject).tag] == targetColor {

        infoText.text = "You have touched the right color!"
    } else {
        infoText.text = "Please touch the \(targetColor) color"
    }


}



@IBAction func generateRandomcolor(_ sender: Any) {

    let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colors.count)));

    targetColor = colors[index];

    infoText.text = "Touch \(targetColor)";
}
```

When I run this code, it seems to report a Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION, for the code `infoText.text = "Touch \(targetColor)";`. I tried searching on similar issues and it states that there is a problem with unwrapping *nil*. However, there isn't *nil* in my code.

I'm still a beginner could you explain to me what I could do to solve this and also how I could troubleshoot these problems to solve it myself?

Thank you!

Comment: Check outlet connection of `infoText` is properly connected or not?

Comment: Oh my goodness! I'm not sure why everything was disconnected! Thank you very much. Do you have any tips for troubleshooting?

Comment: Glad it works for you, now when it is solved batter if you delete the question.